# Two-way Binding when item is removed from list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do you setup two way binding when removing/adding items from a list data structure?
 Currently each item in my listbox displays string values, If i update any of these values i have the two-way binding set through the propertyChanged notify. Although if i remove the item entirely from the list, how do i update the list?
 This is the line i would like to update
Students.CompSciList.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a List that notifies your control if something has changed, e.g. [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Dominik, didn't realize ObservableCollection replaced list.

Comment: Replaced is probably the wrong word.  I still use List when I only need list level bindings since it has less overhead than ObservableCollection.

Comment: @mydogisbox For example, when it will just be displayed. Never modified?

Comment: Right.  Good for combobox options for example.